# Find the mean of the discrete random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Find the mean of A such that A (a discrete random variable) has the distribution $P(X=n)=3^{-n}$ and $n \geq 1$

Comment: Do you know the rule for computing expected value of a discrete variable? What does it say in this case? Where did you get stuck while trying to figure this out?

Comment: You need to find $$\sum xP(X=x)=\sum n3^{-n}$$

Comment: I don't think this topic has been covered in my class yet so I'm not sure how to even attempt this

Comment: For the summation that you've given, what would the limits be? Are they 1 and infinity? If so how would I solve it?

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 1} 3^{-n} \not = 1$

Comment: Are you taking a course in which the term _expected value_ has never been defined, you have never been given _any_ formulas related to it, and suddenly for the first time the words "expected value" came up in this exercise? If so, I feel sad that this sort of thing can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find $$\sum xP(X=x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} n3^{-n}$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=1\times3^{-1}+2\times 3^{-2}+3\times 3^{-3}+...$$multiply by $\frac 13$
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=1\times3^{-1}+2\times 3^{-2}+3\times 3^{-3}+4\times 3^{-4}+...
\\\frac13 \mathbb{E}[X]=1\times3^{-2}+2\times 3^{-3}+3\times 3^{-4}+4\times 3^{-5}++...$$ now find $$\mathbb{E}[X]-\frac13 \mathbb{E}[X]$$
$$\quad{\frac23\mathbb{E}[X]=1\times3^{-1}+(2-1)\times 3^{-2}+(3-2)\times 3^{-3}+(4-3)\times 3^{-4}+...\\=1\times3^{-1}+1\times 3^{-2}+1\times 3^{-3}+1\times 3^{-4}+...\\=\frac{1\times 3^{-1}}{1-3^{-1}}=\frac 12 \\\implies \frac23\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac 12 \to \mathbb{E}[X]=\frac34}$$

Comment: Could you explain what you did on the second last line? How did you get $$\frac{1\times 3^{-1}}{1-3^{-1}}$$

Comment: This is geometric series $$|x|<1,1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\\\lim {n\to \infty} \frac{1-\not {x^{n+1}}}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$and $$\frac{3^{-1}}{1-3^{-1} }\times \frac{3}{3}$$

Comment: Why couldn't this formula have been applied at the beginning for E(X) which would give us $ E(X) = 1/2$?

Comment: Can you see the difference between$$1+x+x^2+x^3+....\\1+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+...$$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, thanks for the help

Comment: $E[X]=\frac34$ is not consistent with $X \ge 1$.  Perhaps you are assuming $P(X=0)=\frac12$